Mac OS shows wrong date and time
My Mac mini M1 mit Sonoma 14.3.1 shows wrong date and time:

10th of April [correct date: 13th of April]
22:52 [correct time: 00:24]

System set do auto time settings with correct time Zone. Restart didn't change anything. Time server set to default.
If I switch to Manual, the system uses the new date/time.
As soon as I switch back to auto, the system immediatly shows the wrong date and time.
Any hints?
Additionally,I right now remember, that the system shows for some weeks (?) 0:00 on the login screen just after system boot.

I would first update to the current version of macOS (14.4.1), which you should do anyway. That probably won't solve the problem. Next you should check whether some third-party software is causing it. To do that, start up in safe mode and see whether there's any difference.

I did this and restarted the system:
sudo rm /var/db/timed/com.apple.timed.plist

After that, MacOS now shows the correct time and date.
Additionally, I updated to 14.4.1.
